# Complex forms of $\sin x$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

If you can rewrite $\cos az + i\sin az = e^{iaz},$ how do you rewrite it when you have $(\sin az)^2 + (\cos az)^2?$

Comment: Sorry, what's your question?

Comment: Nice question! But you have not shown your work for this question due to which this is not suitable for this site. Your question may therefore be downvoted or eventually closed. Learn [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). That's why I am flagging this question as 'needing improvement'.

Comment: It should be $\cos az + i\sin az.$ You left out the $i.$

Comment: **HINT:** Rewrite in terms of exponentials. $\cos^2x+\sin^2 x=\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^2$
What happens when you expand what's inside the parenthesis?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For any $z \, \in \mathbb{C}$
\begin{align}
\cos^2z+\sin^2z&=(\cos z+i\sin z)(\cos z-i\sin z)\\
&=\ldots\\
&=e^0\\
&= \ldots
\end{align}
Where hopefully you can fill in the blanks.